# OS X El Capitan Downloading problem

Tags: mac, macos, mac-appstore, install

I've downloaded OS X El Capitan from the AppStore. If I go AppStore --> Store --> Purchased it says "Downloaded" but I can't seem to prompt the install. I've tried restarting the Download but nothing happens.

Anyone have any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Solved, If you go into Applications there should be an App called "Install OS X El Capitan". Launch from there.